# Merging tags with acts_as_taggable_on Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using [acts_as_taggable_on](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) in my Rails app, and I'd like advice on the best way to merge two tags.

For example, if I've got a list of Food records, and some are tagged "cheese" and some are tagged "milk," what's the best way to combine these tags into a single "dairy" tag.  Should I just find all records tagged with "cheese" and/or "milk," tag those records with the new "dairy" tag, and delete the "cheese" and "milk" tags and taggings, or is there a better way to do this?

I've looked in the gem's docs and specs, and I don't see any dedicated method that would combine multiple tags.  If I go the multi-step route I propose above, do I run any risk of messing up the taggings if one of the steps fails (if some records *don't* become tagged with "dairy" for whatever reason and the "cheese" tags are "deleted)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure that no tags are changed unless all the changes are successful, use a database transaction.  The code would look something like this:

```
Food.transaction do
  Food.tagged_with('milk', 'cheese').each do |food|
    food.tag_list -= ['milk', 'cheese']
    food.tag_list << 'dairy'
    food.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: this is not answer !!!
this is static way to merge tags !!
what about merge tags in public situation !!?